# Scala.js TypeError: $g.DOMParser is not a constructor

Tags: scala.js

I'm new to Scala.js and I'm just trying to write a test that will parse some html files. I'm trying to create a DOMParser:

```
val parser = new DOMParser
```

But I get the following error

```
scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: TypeError: $g.DOMParser is not a constructor
```

DOMParser is defined as

```
@js.native
class DOMParser extends js.Object {
  def parseFromString(source: String, mimeType: String): Document =   js.native
}
```

Thank

Answer (score 1):

After reading around, it looks like I needed to do this

```
val parser = js.Dynamic.global.DOMParser
```

If anyone can explain why, that would be appreciated :)

Comment: i just executed `    dom.window.console.log(new DOMParser)` no erros in my chrome console and  i see new object created. can you please tell more about your environment ..

Comment: I was trying to run unit tests in my IDE (intelliJ)

Comment: looks like environment issue, node.js ? did you installed jsdom ? and have this setting ` jsDependencies += RuntimeDOM`  ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "environment"? I'm running unit tests. There is no browser.

What is jsdom? What does the jsDependencies line do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `val parser = new DOMParser()`, the `()` is required for constructor to work properly. There is no need to use `js.Dynamic` in this case